# error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c, system-calls

I have a class called traffic.c

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>    

    struct cs1550_sem{
        int value;
     };
    void down(cs1550_sem* sem) //error
    {
        syscall(_NR_cs1550_down, sem);
    }
    void up(cs1550_sem* sem) //error
    {
        syscall(__NR_cs1550_up, sem);   
    }
    int main(){
        struct cs1550_sem sample;
        sample->value = 0;
        down(sample);
        up(sample);
        return 0;
    }
```

I declared the sys calls elsewhere in sys.c, unistd.c and put them in the sys call table. I don't know why the void functions are giving me this error. I checked previous answers and tried their solutions, but to no avail.

Comment: `void down(cs1550_sem* sem)` You need to add struct to the parameter type so it should be `void down(struct cs1550_sem* sem)` or you can use `typedef struct cs1550_sem cs1550_sem` so you can stop putting struct before you declare variables of the type struct

Answer (score 1):

You need `struct cs1550_sem` everywhere you use it - the error you are getting is related to it not being present in the function prototypes.

Comment: In `main` it suddenly gets used as a pointer. Oh well, time to get back to the study books.

Comment: Because you put `*` in the function calls that means the function needs a pointer. Also using `->` requires a pointer, you should use `.` instead. You should use &sample to pass to the functions. Though probably better also make sure the system call really needs a pointer.